# Does Safari on iOS support the DNS Prefetch directive?

Tags: ios, html, ios4, mobile-safari

I've recently come across the DNS Prefetch directive as part of the HTML5 Boilerplate template.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching#HTML5_prefetching):

> Prefetching is not currently explicitly defined by any accepted standards, but Mozilla have announced work on an Internet Draft, that will match the implementation in Firefox.
>
> ```
> <link rel="prefetch" href="http://www.example.com/">
> ```

I read information that back in September 2010, there was a [fix for Safari 5.0.1](http://www.macworld.com/article/154149/2010/09/dns_prefetching.html) that fixed slow/stalled page loads when DNS Prefetch directives were present. However, I couldn't any information on whether **Safari on iOS** supports the DNS Prefetch.

We are building some HTML 5 pages that are loaded exclusively in a UIWebView within an iOS app. On this page there are a few external resources we're loading so I'd like to improve page load times and use the DNS Prefetch if it's going to help.

Comment: For dns-prefetching you need to use `rel="dns-prefetch"` as `rel="prefetch"` will actually load the url (in the background), instead of just doing the DNS lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately can't give a satisfying complete answer, but definitely not before iOs 4.3.3 according to http://osdir.com/ml/phonegap/2011-07/msg00770.html

Answer (score 1):

According to CanIUse.com, prefetch is unsupported by both mobile and iOS versions of Safari. At the time of this post, that covered version 10.0.

[Can I Use... Resource Hints: prefetch](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prefetch)

If prefetching is necessary for those platforms, there are [several possible work arounds](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/). Most of them function by referencing the preload resource in CSS/JavaScript prior to using it on the page.

Comment: As @Gerben said in their comment the OP want's to use [`rel="dns-prefetch"` (link)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-dns-prefetch) rather than `rel="prefetch"` which as of writing this seems to be supported on Safari but not iOS Safari.